# Hide "fill" together with another trace [link traces?!]

Tags: python, plot, graphics, plotly, spyder

I extracted a bit of code from: https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/#filled-lines.
I created something similar for my research, but what I want to accomplish if I deselect trace named "Fair", I want to hide the filled area (in my example the confidence interval). Is there something like link-traces or something? I searched numerous options but can't seem the solution.

[With trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHt0B.png)

[Without trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXw4c.png)

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='browser'

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x_rev = x[::-1]

# Line 1
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1_upper = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
y1_lower = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1_lower = y1_lower[::-1]



fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x+x_rev,
    y=y1_upper+y1_lower,
    fill='toself',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
    line_color='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    showlegend=False,
    name='Fair',
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x, y=y1,
    line_color='rgb(0,100,80)',
    name='Fair',
))


fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.show()
```

Comment: You could use event functions, as an example see https://plotly.com/python/click-events/

Comment: Thanks Amir, I'll am struggling with the event functions now (started python yesterday, fimiliar with MatLab and R, so hopefully I'll get the solution...)

Comment: Nice. I hope you could get the solution soon. Cheers

Comment: Hmm.. can't seem to find the solution. But that is probably more due to the dash code / adding the data with the above example. And unfortunately getting the part to hide another trace when pushing on hiding one in the legend...